# Start and Stop thread using QAction toggled

Tags: multithreading, pyqt5, qaction

I'm currently trying to build a PyQt5 app and it should consist of the main GUI and in the background there should be a different thread that should measure something in an infinite loop. And I want to start and stop this thread using a QAction or Checkbox.

So to say when I press the checkbox and the state is true the thread should be started and if I click it again it should be stopped.

Now what is the best way to implement this?

Currently I'm using a Worker thread like this:

```
class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self._isRunning = True

    def task(self):
        if not self._isRunning:
            self._isRunning = True
        while self._isRunning:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            ... measure ...

    def stop(self):
        self._isRunning = False
```

and this in the main thread to make it run:

```
self.thread = QtCore.QThread()
self.thread.start()
self.worker = Worker()
self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)

self.btn_start.clicked.connect(self.worker.task)
self.btn_stopped.clicked.connect(lambda: self.worker.stop())
```

So far this works. But I'm not really confident that this is the best way to do it and I'd also like it much better if I could make the same thing using a checkbox in the way described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, the code you've posted is not multi-threaded. This is because `worker.task()` is started by code in the main thread, so it will also run in the main thread. You need to use the worker thread's `started` signal to start the task, and a custom signal on the worker to quit the thread.

The demo script below should fix these issues:

```
import sys, time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    messageSent = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self._isRunning = False

    def task(self):
        print('WKR thread:', QtCore.QThread.currentThread())
        self._isRunning = True
        count = 0
        while self._isRunning:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            count += 1
            self.messageSent.emit('count: %s' % count)
        self.finished.emit()

    def stop(self):
        self._isRunning = False

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('Test', self)
        self.button.toggled.connect(self.handleButton)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.task)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.messageSent.connect(self.label.setText)

    def handleButton(self, checked=False):
        print('GUI thread:', QtCore.QThread.currentThread())
        if checked:
            self.label.clear()
            self.thread.start()
        else:
            self.worker.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(800, 150, 200, 50)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @haxor789. You're right about `stop()` - it was just something left over from an earlier version. I've updated the demo to include changing a label.