# Problems getting QTimer to start when using QThread

Tags: python, pyqt5, signals-slots, qthread, qtimer

I'm trying to implement a webcam using PyQt5 from an example I found ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52476344/10944175), but not really relevant).
Getting the example to work wasn't an issue, but I wanted to modify some things and I am stuck on one particular problem.

I have two classes, one QObject `Capture` which has a QBasicTimer that I want to start, and a QWidget `MyWidget` with a button that is supposed to start the timer of the `Capture` object, which is inside a QThread.

If I directly connect the button click to the method that starts the timer, everything works fine.

But I want to do some other things when I click the button, so I connected the button to a method of `MyWidget` first and call the `start` method of `Capture` from there. This, however, doesn't work: the timer doesn't start.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys

class Capture(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Capture, self).__init__(parent)

        self.m_timer = QtCore.QBasicTimer()

    def start(self):
        print("capture start called")
        self.m_timer.start(1000, self)

    def timerEvent(self, event):
        print("time event")


class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)    

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.btn_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start")
        lay.addWidget(self.btn_start)        

        self.capture = Capture()
        captureThread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        captureThread.start()
        self.capture.moveToThread(captureThread)
        
        # self.btn_start.clicked.connect(self.capture.start) # this works
        self.btn_start.clicked.connect(self.startCapture) # this doesn't
        # self.capture.start() # this doesn't either
        
        self.show()
        
    def startCapture(self):
        self.capture.start()


def run_app():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MyWidget()
    mainWin.show()
    app.exec_()

run_app()
```

It is some problem with the QThread, because if I don't use threading it works. I thought maybe it has something to do with the thread not being in some way available when called from a different method than the one it was created in, but calling `self.capture.start()` directly from the `init` does not work either.

I only have a very basic grasp of threads. Can someone tell me how I can properly call `self.capture.start()` from `MyWidget` and why it works without problems when directly connecting it to the button click?

Comment: You could connect the `clicked` signal to *both* `capture.start` *and* another function that does what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you connect the button's `clicked` signal to the worker's `start` slot, Qt will automatically detect that it's a cross-thread connection. When the signal is eventually emitted, it will be queued in the receiving thread's event-queue, which ensures the slot will be called within the worker thread.

However, if you connect the button's `clicked` signal to the `startCapture` slot, there's no cross-thread connection, because the slot belongs to `MyWidget` (which lives in the main thread). When the signal is emitted this time, the slot tries to create the timer from within the main thread, which is not supported. Timers must always be started within the thread that creates them (otherwise Qt will print a message like "QBasicTimer::start: Timers cannot be started from another thread").

A better approach is to connect the `started` and `finished` signals of the thread to some `start` and `stop` slots in the worker, and then call the thread's `start` and `quit` methods to control the worker. Here's a demo based on your script, which shows how to implement that:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys

class Capture(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Capture, self).__init__(parent)
        self.m_timer = QtCore.QBasicTimer()

    def start(self):
        print("capture start called")
        self.m_timer.start(1000, self)

    def stop(self):
        print("capture stop called")
        self.m_timer.stop()

    def timerEvent(self, event):
        print("time event")

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.btn_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start")
        lay.addWidget(self.btn_start)
        self.capture = Capture()
        self.captureThread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        self.capture.moveToThread(self.captureThread)
        self.captureThread.started.connect(self.capture.start)
        self.captureThread.finished.connect(self.capture.stop)
        self.btn_start.clicked.connect(self.startCapture)
        self.show()

    def startCapture(self):
        if not self.captureThread.isRunning():
            self.btn_start.setText('Stop')
            self.captureThread.start()
        else:
            self.btn_start.setText('Start')
            self.stopCapture()

    def stopCapture(self):
        self.captureThread.quit()
        self.captureThread.wait()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.stopCapture()

def run_app():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MyWidget()
    mainWin.show()
    app.exec_()

run_app()
```

Comment: This is working great, thank you! I'm just wondering if there could be some blocking issues if I stop the thread before calling the "stop" method of Capture, in case it takes some time to "close" the camera.

Comment: Also, it's good to know that PyQt automatically knows it is a cross-thread connection when connecting a button. Is there a way to do that with regular calls to the Capture class methods?

Comment: @FreyaW You should *mostly* think in terms of communicating between threads using signals and slots. It's hard to be more specific, because the exact implementation depends on the nature of the background task. If the task has discrete steps, it's quite easy to handle (e.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38815580/984421)). However, an uninterruptable task that blocks until it finishes is much harder to deal with. For that, you'd probably need to use multi-processing instead, since python doesn't support true concurrency (due to its [GIL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1294382/984421)).